# Valgrind giving errors with getline()

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I have a function which calls `getline()`, which reads lines from a standard text file. These lines end in `\r\n`, as this is what the spec calls for as it is the "internet standard" for VCARD files.

Anyway, I run this baby through Valgrind on OpenSUSE 11.3 with the latest GCC and Valgrind versions; no errors. However, for reasons of no relevance to this problem, I switched distros to Back Track 4 (Ubuntu based), and now I am getting a metric ton of Valgrind errors:

```
    ==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x40164A1: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4007C04: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4002A2C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x40164AC: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4007C04: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4002A2C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
--21536-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x55
--21536-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x55
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
--21536-- DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled CFI instruction 0:10
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x400B217: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x40031D0: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x400AF0F: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x40031D0: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x400B27A: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x40031D0: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x400A5DE: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x40030FE: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x400A5E6: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x40030FE: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x400AF0F: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x40030FE: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4014206: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000C6C: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x4000856: (within /lib/ld-2.11.1.so)
==21536==
==21536== Invalid read of size 8
==21536==    at 0x40B4785: (within /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x8049EFB: main (vcutil.c:496)
==21536==  Address 0x419d1b0 is 8 bytes before a block of size 120 alloc'd
==21536==    at 0x4025D2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
==21536==    by 0x409DF9D: getdelim (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x408F3A2: getline (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x804947C: getUnfolded (vcutil.c:299)
==21536==    by 0x8049EFB: main (vcutil.c:496)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x40B47AD: (within /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==21536==    by 0x8049EFB: main (vcutil.c:496)
==21536==
==21536== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21536==    at 0x8049524: getUnfolded (vcutil.c:307)
==21536==    by 0x8049EFB: main (vcutil.c:496)
```

I especially don't know what the lines refering to

```
--21536-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x55
```

mean. These are new since I changed distros.

Anyway, for reference, here is my function in question:

```
VcStatus getUnfolded (FILE *const vcf, char **const buff) {

    //int const buffSize = 30;
    size_t lineSize = 0;
    int done = 0;  //Set to one if the next line checked does not entail unfolding
    static char* queue = NULL;  //A queue to store the next line read in
    static int lineNum = 0;  
    char* buffer = NULL;  //The dynamic memory that will be linked to buf
    int valid_line = 0;  //Set to one if the line contains characters other then whitespace
    char* temp; //Used to point to the location of \r\n in the buffer

    VcStatus error;  //Initialize VcStatus with appropriate values
    error.code = OK;
    error.linefrom = lineNum;
    error.lineto = 0;

    //Special case for resetting getUnfolded()
    if (vcf == NULL){      
        lineNum = 0;
        if (queue != NULL) queue = NULL;
        error.linefrom = 0;
        error.lineto = 0;
        return error;
    }

    //Copies any string contained in queue from last time into buffer
    if (queue != NULL) {
        buffer = malloc (strlen (queue)+1);
        strcpy (buffer, queue);
        strcpy (queue, "");
    }

    //If the end of file has been reached, last line is returned.
    if (feof (vcf) != 0) {
        queue = NULL;
        lineNum += 1;
        if (buffer != NULL) {
          if (strcmp (buffer, "") != 0)*buff = buffer;
        }
        else *buff = NULL;
        return error;
    }

    while (done == 0) {

        //Gets a new line from the vcf file, and returns null if there is no more data to be returned
        getline (&queue, &lineSize, vcf);

        if (ferror(vcf) != 0) {
          error.code = IOERR;
          return error;
        }

        //Sets valid_line to 1 if the line read in contains any characters other then whitespace
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen (queue); i++){
            if (queue[i] != '\r' && queue[i] != '\n' && queue[i] != ' ' && queue[i] != '\t') valid_line = 1;
        }

        if (feof (vcf) && valid_line == 0) {
            queue = NULL;
            break;
        }        

        if (valid_line == 1){
            //Finds the 'internet standard' newline and replaces it with a null terminator
            temp = strstr (queue, "\r\n");
            if (temp != NULL) strcpy (temp, "\0");

            //Sets the buffer equal to contents of queue and resets queue if buffer is empty
            if (buffer == NULL) {

                buffer = malloc (strlen (queue)+1);
                lineNum = lineNum + 1;          
                strcpy (buffer, queue);
                strcpy (queue, "");

            //Checks for leading whitespace to indicate a folded line, and unfolds
            }else if (queue [0] == ' ' || queue [0] == '\t') {

                lineNum = lineNum + 1;
                buffer = realloc (buffer, strlen (buffer)+strlen (queue)+2);
                strcat (buffer, queue+1);
                strcpy (queue, "");

            //If both conditions above are false, buffer contains the next valid line
            }else{

                error.lineto = lineNum;
                lineNum += 1;
                done = 1;

            }
        }
    }

    *buff = buffer;

    return error;

}
```

...And the dummy function to send test data to it:

```
int main () {

    FILE* fp = fopen ("test.vcf", "r");

    char * buff;

    getUnfolded (fp, &buff);

}
```

***The test.vcf file is just a simple text file really***

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: That is pretty funny about the google thing :P goes to show you I had no luck googling that problem if this is the first result.
And yes, I have recompiled multiple times on this new host, and the source has not changed... The test.vcf file is using the proper EOL CRLF... It's quite a vexing problem!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the 'dwarf2 opcode' errors are probably just you moving to a version of valgrind older than the compiler you're using, and can be safely ignored.  About your error: you call `strlen(queue)`.  What happens if the line is longer than `lineSize`?  If you come to the conclusion that the code is OK, you can generate a suppressions file to get on with your life.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's nice to understand why valgrind is spewing crap at me that makes no sense at all! I would be interested to learn how to suppress those errors if you know how? And I have no Idea how to work around that error you are referring to. In my understanding, that strlen(queue) line is called if queue has something in it from the last time the function was called. I keep getting errors like "uninitialized variable used in comparision" because my variables have been initialized in conditional statements (in every case), and I don't know how to get rid of those either.

Comment: Oh and that lineSize variable is pointless; I am going to hardcode the 0 into getline instead. Getline will just resize the buffer "automagially" anyway, so I don't even see the point of the "suggested buffer size" :S

Comment: @Borealid - You sir are my hero. I downloaded the most recent version of valgrind, compiled it, and I now have ZERO errors. Thank you, and case closed ladies and gentlemen. The fat lady has sung :D

Comment: What do you regard as 'latest GCC and Valgrind versions'?  GCC 4.5.2, Valgrind 3.6.1?

Comment: @araisbec, if @borealid doesn't provide his answer as an answer, please do take the time to put the final result in as an answer to your own question -- then next time someone googles similar questions, it'll be obvious what the final result is. :)

Comment: @araisbec, it is interesting what a little googling will find: http://www.uoguelph.ca/~gardnerw/courses/cis2750/asmts.htm

Comment: @Seth, why is that relevant? The question is about using Valgrind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of valgrind you are using is outdated and so it is not suppressing the correct output. Those errors are still there on suse they are just suppressed because they are in system code.

You need to manually install the newest version of valgrind

This is the forum post I used

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1608001